# Unity WebGL Build Error. All Sprite Images Turned into White Squares After Build

Tags: unity-game-engine, webgl

I’m new to WebGL and wanted to ask if I have missed a step regarding WebGL Build. In the editor the game run just fine but after building it, all of the textures suddenly gone. Here’s a ss on what it looked like including the error. As you can see in the error image below, the button is still there but it just won’t show the texture.
[image]

Here's the stacktrace error

```
Unknown error occurred while loading 'sharedassets0.assets'.

_JS_Log_Dump @ 1.0.1.9.framework.js.gz:2
$func6116 @ 1.0.1.9.wasm.gz:0x3266bb
$func6118 @ 1.0.1.9.wasm.gz:0x32683f
$func6113 @ 1.0.1.9.wasm.gz:0x326563
$func6112 @ 1.0.1.9.wasm.gz:0x325db1
$func6870 @ 1.0.1.9.wasm.gz:0x370559
$func6859 @ 1.0.1.9.wasm.gz:0x36f070
$func6670 @ 1.0.1.9.wasm.gz:0x35723d
$func6669 @ 1.0.1.9.wasm.gz:0x356e0a
$func6656 @ 1.0.1.9.wasm.gz:0x35561a
$func6653 @ 1.0.1.9.wasm.gz:0x355147
$func6652 @ 1.0.1.9.wasm.gz:0x355106
$func701 @ 1.0.1.9.wasm.gz:0x1147b4
$func9512 @ 1.0.1.9.wasm.gz:0x433839
$func13429 @ 1.0.1.9.wasm.gz:0x5caac1
$func13509 @ 1.0.1.9.wasm.gz:0x5d8097
$func13432 @ 1.0.1.9.wasm.gz:0x5caeee
$func13648 @ 1.0.1.9.wasm.gz:0x5edc78
$func13647 @ 1.0.1.9.wasm.gz:0x5ed5b9
$func13430 @ 1.0.1.9.wasm.gz:0x5cace1
$func13415 @ 1.0.1.9.wasm.gz:0x5c9098
$func13388 @ 1.0.1.9.wasm.gz:0x5c3916
$func13386 @ 1.0.1.9.wasm.gz:0x5c2b26
$func13355 @ 1.0.1.9.wasm.gz:0x5c1ee0
$func13045 @ 1.0.1.9.wasm.gz:0x59ce61
$func13045 @ 1.0.1.9.wasm.gz:0x59ce76
$func13040 @ 1.0.1.9.wasm.gz:0x59c9fb
$func13033 @ 1.0.1.9.wasm.gz:0x59ac72
$func13183 @ 1.0.1.9.wasm.gz:0x5abf72
$dynCall_vi @ 1.0.1.9.wasm.gz:0x27309b7
(anonymous) @ 1.0.1.9.framework.js.gz:2
dynCall @ 1.0.1.9.framework.js.gz:2
dynCall_wrapper @ 1.0.1.9.framework.js.gz:2
wrapper @ 1.0.1.9.framework.js.gz:2
(anonymous) @ 1.0.1.9.framework.js.gz:2
```

and here's my htaccess config

```
<IfModule mod_mime.c>
    RemoveType .mem
    RemoveType .data
    RemoveType .unity3d
    RemoveType .jsbr
    RemoveType .membr
    RemoveType .databr
    RemoveType .unity3dbr
    RemoveType .jsgz
    RemoveType .memgz
    RemoveType .datagz
    RemoveType .unity3dgz
    AddType application/octet-stream .mem
    AddType application/octet-stream .data
    AddType application/octet-stream .unity3d
    AddType application/octet-stream .jsbr
    AddType application/octet-stream .membr
    AddType application/octet-stream .databr
    AddType application/octet-stream .unity3dbr
    AddType application/octet-stream .jsgz
    AddType application/octet-stream .memgz
    AddType application/octet-stream .datagz
    AddType application/octet-stream .unity3dgz

    # The following lines are required for builds without decompression fallback, compressed with gzip
    RemoveType .gz
    AddEncoding gzip .gz
    AddType application/gzip .data.gz
    AddType application/wasm .wasm.gz
    AddType application/javascript .js.gz
    AddType application/octet-stream .symbols.json.gz

    # The following lines are required for builds without decompression fallback, compressed with Brotli
    RemoveType .br
    RemoveLanguage .br
    AddEncoding br .br
    AddType application/octet-stream .data.br
    AddType application/wasm .wasm.br
    AddType application/javascript .js.br
    AddType application/octet-stream .symbols.json.br

    # The following line improves loading performance for uncompressed builds
    AddType application/wasm .wasm

    # Uncomment the following line to improve loading performance for gzip-compressed builds with decompression fallback
    AddEncoding gzip .unityweb

    # Uncomment the following line to improve loading performance for brotli-compressed builds with decompression fallback
    # AddEncoding br .unityweb

</IfModule>
```

Comment: This doesnt look like the unity suggested stuff - but it also depends on the version of unity as it has changed a few times.  What was the first error? did it moan about headers? did you upload the whole build tree?

Comment: As far as I know that's the only error. The htaccess was derived from a forum about another WebGL crash and I thought it was the same. It did not actually moan about header and yes I upload the whole build tree in my local Apache server. I'm using XAMPP.

Comment: well you should be able to catch it early and scroll to the top  to check there are no other issues - reason i ask is apache/iis apparently for newer versions of unity now have to send a header to lie about the file type, because just having the mime type isnt enough....

Comment: Oh I see, do you know where can I find the header example? I'll try to look into it again

Comment: I just checked again; the only error is still the same which is the 'sharedassets0.assets'

Comment: I just found out someone else had the same issue but there's no answer https://forum.unity.com/threads/guys-what-happend-with-my-webgl-project-here-is-a-bug-or-something-i-never-meet.1490728/

Comment: where to find the config? unitys documentation.  are you using asset streaming? is it on https? did you need to tick the allow http?

Comment: For the config, I already used the one from documentation. It still resulted in the same result even if I changed the .htaccess or the httpd.conf. I used asset streaming in this project using Addressables but have disabled it for WebGL. And yes, it uses https:// instead of http://

Comment: @BugFinder I don't think the issue lies in Addressables as the base UI for our game is already included in the build but still failed to show when we switched to WebGL

Comment: no but it rules out one more issue.. So, sharedassets0 is not a normal webgl file (eg if you make a blank webgl project you dont get it) so, the question is what is this file doing.  Have you tried deleting the library folder and rebuilding?

Comment: Yes, I have tried rebuilding the project and deleting its library content. It resulted in the same error. I'm gonna try to rebuilding it one more time and deleting all the addressables from the group and see if it will made any changes

Comment: @BugFinder does choosing between Linear and Gamma has any effect? The editor forced me to choose between them or delete webgl 1.0. Currently I'm using Linear and WebGL 2.0 and deleted the 1.0 as per the systems reccomend

Comment: it wouldnt cause that no  - which version of unity are you on?

Comment: It's 2020.3.38f1, but i don't think it's the editor's issue as I created a blank project and tried to build it and it worked just fine.

Comment: no i was more puzzled by how you had webgl 1 as an option :P so, theres something about your build thats creating the shared assets file. You would need to identify what that is as either somehow its not being built, or the web server is handing it out incorrectly, or, other random parts.

Comment: I see, got it we'll look it up

Comment: So after reviewing the build using full stack trace it said that it is the problem with shader and textmeshpro shader. The errors are 'UnityEngine.ResourcesAPIInternal:FindShaderByName(String)' and 'TMPro.ShaderUtilities:GetShaderPropertyIDs()' and also 'TMPro.TextMeshProUGUI:LoadFontAsset()'

Comment: Will try to look up which asset makings the error. As we don't know the exact asset making this error, do you have advice on the approaches for finding the asset?

Comment: the shader.. meh.. dont worry, however it depends what the errors are for the findshaderbyname and tmpro stuff